# onsubmit: Not submitting data when form redirects

Tags: javascript, php, html, redirect

I'm attempting to get a button to redirect to the "viewing" page after it submits its data.

My code seems to either a) submit the data or b) redirect to the page.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="window.location.href='viewPost.php?id=<?= $lastId ?>'; return false;">
```

^ This way, it only redirects; however, when I remove the "return false" at the end, it submits properly yet does not redirect at all.

I've tried redirecting via JavaScript functions and onClick events that I've read about on this and other websites, but this is the only way it has worked to redirect properly for some reason.

How can I ensure my data is sent as well as have my form redirect to the viewing page?

Update: The rest of my form looks like this...

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="window.location.href='viewPost.php?id=<?= $last$
<span id="postContent">
<textarea name="postText" autofocus></textarea>
</span>
<div align="center" style="margin-top: 1%">
<input name="read" type="submit" value="Read" class="read" /> &nbsp;
<input name="submit" type="submit" value="Save" class="save" />
</div>
</form>
```

Update 2: Here is how I am sending the data, this is in my index.php:

```
<?php
if ($_POST['submit']) {
$postName = $_POST['title'];
$id = $_POST['id'];
mysql_connect ("localhost", "myuser", "mypassword") or die ('Error: ' . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("notes") or die ('Data error:' . mysql_error());
$text = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['postText']);
$query="INSERT INTO notes (title,text) VALUES ('$postName','$text')";
mysql_query($query) or die ('Error updating database' . mysql_error());
}
?>
```

Comment: One question, if you are using a form, why are you redirecting via JS? What is the other content in your form?

Comment: you forgot to add `?>` after echo statement?

Comment: You forgot end the <?php in action. It should be action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" instead of action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];"

Comment: Updating the original post to clarify, it's basically only a textarea and a couple buttons.
Also fixed the `?>` error in my code, but it still doesn't submit...

Comment: Downvoted because your paste of code contains errors that are in addition to any errors you actually have on your page.  Please paste your code EXACTLY as you have it, don't re-type it as this will bring in more errors.

Comment: Noted, and code has been revised to reflect more accurately.

Answer (score 3):

When you submit an ordinary form, the browser POSTs the data to the URL given in `action`, then renders the document with which the server responds. However, if you use `onsubmit` with `return false`, it cancels the default behavior and the form will not be submitted.

The easiest way for you to solve this will be to modify the PHP script to redirect the browser (using [`header("Location: ...")`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)) after the POSTed data has been processed. If you want to make this optional, you could use a hidden `input` in the form:

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
  <input type="hidden" name="redirect_to"
    value="viewPost.php?id=<?php echo $lastId ?>"/>

  <!-- ...the rest of your form... -->
</form>
```

Then in the PHP:

```
<?php
  // ...process the POSTed data...

  if( in_array('redirect_to', $_POST) ) {
    header("Location: " . $_POST['redirect_to']);
  }
?>
```

My PHP is a bit rusty, but hopefully you get the idea. Using the Location header requires that the PHP script doesn't send any output (HTML, `echo`, etc.), but if you're redirecting the user right away you shouldn't be sending any output anyway. (If you still want to send output in some cases, you should do it in an `else` branch after the `if` above.) You don't really need JavaScript at all for this.

Comment: I tried this method, but it didn't work for me unfortunately; the page did not redirect to the viewPost location.

Answer (score 1):

You could redirect direct from php file where you process your data.
YOUR FORM CALL

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
```

PHP CODE

```
   //YOUR PROCESSSING CODE HERE
   header('Location: viewPost.php?id=' . $lastId );
```

It is important to keep in mind that header must be used if you have not use html tags, print, echo or any other function that write to DOM before use it, if not you wil get an error

Comment: Will this work with my setup? I'm not quite sure how to implement it without having a page constantly redirecting...
My index.php displays the form and accepts data/sends it to the database after the Submit button is clicked, then it should redirect to the viewPost.php page which displays the info from the database. How can I weave the method you recommend into this setup?
Pardon my ignorance, I'm confused at it...

Comment: Are you posting the data via AJAX?

Comment: To my (limited) knowledge, no; I'm using PHP to interface with my database using SQL. I'll update the post to reflect it so you can see what I mean...

Answer (score 0):

When you use window.location.href you redirect the entire page, and data in form is not passed to the URL.

You can use action value in form, or you can create a function that append data to the url and then, do the window.location.href

Example:

HTML:

```
 <form ... onsubmit="doStuff()" data-url="viewPost.php?id=<?= $lastId ?>">
```

Javascript:

```
    function doStuff(){
        var url = $("form").attr("data-url");
        url += '&field1='+$("form [name='field1']").val();
        ...
        window.location.href = url
    }
```

Comment: This didn't work for me unfortunately, I have this as my redirect function like yours said:
`function redirect() {
      var url = $("form").attr("data-url");
      url += '&field1='+$("form [name='field1']").val();
      window.location.href = url;
    }
`
And this as my form code:
`<form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" onsubmit="redirect()" data-url="viewPost.php?id=<?= $lastId ?>">
`

It does not redirect the page to viewPost.php for me. I'm not sure what the issue could be :/